# Is $\sec^2\theta - \tan^2\theta=1$ not true at $\theta=\pi/2$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

We know the trigonometric identity; $$\sec^2\theta - \tan^2\theta = 1$$
But $\sec\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ are not defined at $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. So does that mean the above identity is not true at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: Identities are defined whenever both sides of the equation are defined.

Comment: It is a removable singularity.  That is, $\lim_\limits{\theta \to \frac {\pi}{2}} \sec^2\theta - \tan^2\theta = 1$  but $\sec^2 \frac {\pi}{2} - \tan^2 \frac {\pi}{2}$ is undefined.